How can I refresh component every N seconds until some condition?
I would like to refresh a component every 5 seconds, but when I hit a stop condition I stop the rerender.
The actual code is:
const [status,setStatus ] = useState(''); //0:failed, 1:waiting, 2:success

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime(new Date());
        if(status!='2' && status!='0'){ //if succes or fail STOP CALLING THE API
            handleClickRefresh()
        }
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);

const handleClickRefresh = async () => {
    axios.get('...', {
        headers: {
            ...
    }
    }).then((res) =>{
        if(res.status==202){
            setStatus('1'); //waiting
        }else if(res.status==200){
            setStatus('2'); //success
        }
    }).catch(
        function (error) {
            setStatus('0'); //fail
        }
    );
}

The problem seems to be that I can't read "status" correctly, because when the component refresh status comes back to be == '' it resets to starting value.
How can I solve the problem?

Why are you using if(status!='2' && status!='0') instead of if (status === '1')? You initialize status to an empty string so that is likely part of your bug.

The bug along can be fixed by using useRef rather than useState. Since you haven't included state in the deps you will always get it as ''. This is because the useEffect during the first run makes a closure. Another reason why you shouldn't use useState in the example you have shared is that it will cause your interval to mess up (API succeeds in 1 second -> useEffect runs again because of deps -> interval is triggered for N + 1 seconds rather than every N seconds) and cause a re-render of your react component (which might be unnecessary if state is just used as above)
Your code also suffers from an edge case. If the API doesn't succeed within the N seconds (which is possible in production with unforseen network delays or loads) then you will end up making more than one API call and overwhelming the server. Also for the example above prefer === check rather than == for added safety
Here's the updated code which should work
const cachedPromise = useRef();
const apiStatus = useRef(''); //0:failed, 1:waiting, 2:success

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime(new Date());
        if(apiStatus.current === '1'){ //if succes or fail STOP CALLING THE API
            handleClickRefresh()
        }
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);

const handleClickRefresh = () => {
    if (cachedPromise.current) {
      return cachedPromise.current
    }
    cachedPromise.current = axios.get('...', {
        headers: {
            ...
    }
    }).then((res) =>{
        if(res.status === 202) {
            apiStatus.current = '1'; //waiting
        }else if(res.status==200){
            apiStatus.current = '2'; //success
        }
    }).catch(
        function (error) {
            apiStatus.current = '0'; //fail
        }
    ).finally(() => {cachedPromise.current = null}); //reset the cached promise for the next run
}


Why using async then no await? just simplify it: get rid of the then and use await. Furthermore, instead of caching a Promise, just use a boolean: busy/not busy.

@MarioVernari By using a promise, you can keep the method's return the same. Which makes it easy to call the same method again without checking its return. Thanks for pointing out about the async, it was copied from the posters code and I didn't notice it

You can access the current status value from within its setter function, like so:
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  setTime(new Date());
  setStatus(currentStatus => {
    if (currentStatus != '2' && currentStatus != '0') {
      handleClickRefresh();
    }
    return currentStatus;
  }
}, 5000);

There might be a more elegant approach, but this will work too.

The problem is that you missing the status as a dependency in useEffect.
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime(new Date());
        if(status!='2' && status!='0'){ //if succes or fail STOP CALLING THE API
            handleClickRefresh()
        }
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [status]);


I realise you're asking for specific code, but I would argue that we shouldn't all be reinventing the wheel.
Instead, have you considered using a well established library for it?
Since you're using Axios, I'll provide two well established options to use with Axios, with examples.
axios-retry
You could use axios-retry to extend your existing Axios instance.
import axios from 'axios'
import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry'

const myClient = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://example.com' });
axiosRetry(myClient , { retries: 3 });

Then in your component
const handleClickRefresh = async () => {
  myClient.get('http://example.com/test') // The first request fails and the second returns 'ok'
    .then(result => {
      result.data; // 'ok'
    });

For more information see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-retry
SWR
Since you are making requests directly from your UI, you might consider using  SWR for it.
It can use Axios as a fetcher and already includes automatic retries, including features like Exponential backoff out-of-the-box.
import axios from 'axios'

const myClient = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://example.com' });
const myFetcher = url => myClient.get(url).then(res => res.data)

Then in your component
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useSWR('/api/data', myFetcher)
  if (isLoading) return <>Loading</>
  if (error) return <>Oops!</>
  return <>{data}</>
}

For more information see: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started
SWR + onErrorRetry override
You can also override the onErrorRetry behaviour (however note you then also need to implement incremental backoff yourself).
useSWR('/api/user', fetcher, {
  onErrorRetry: (error, key, config, revalidate, { retryCount }) => {
    // Never retry on 404.
    if (error.status === 404) return
 
    // Never retry for a specific key.
    if (key === '/api/user') return
 
    // Only retry up to 10 times.
    if (retryCount >= 10) return
 
    // Retry after 5 seconds.
    setTimeout(() => revalidate({ retryCount }), 5000)
  }
})

For more info see: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/error-handling#error-retry
